# Intellij windows-like bindings on mac?

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA for MAC allows you to change keymap to Eclipse (Mac) or Eclipse (windows). The Windows Eclipse version has windows style editor bindings like control-right moves cursor right one word instead of switching to next editor tab.   How do we load an option for the Windows Intellij (instead of Windows Eclipse) on our Mac, so that cursor movement keys can be more windows-like?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean changing the corresponding shortcuts in the "IntelliJ IDEA Classic" keymap, please try the following:

1. Disable Ctrl + Left / Right shortcuts in OS Preferences | Keyboard | Shortcuts (e.g. on Mac OS 11.5.2 they are dedicated for moving between spaces in Mission control).
2. Open the IDE Preferences | Keymap, choose the IntelliJ IDEA Classic.
3. Assign other keys to the Select Next / Previous Tab actions in Preferences | Keymap | Main Menu | Window | Editor tabs.
4. Assign Ctrl + Left / Right shortcuts to Preferences | Keymap | Editor Actions | Move Caret to Previous / Next Word.